# How to connect View and ViewModel with respect to screen rotation?

Tags: android, android-viewmodel

One promise of the ViewModel is, that it survives cases like rotation of the screen. I still try to figure out how to organise this in practice.

On certain events of the model the View should update. There are two major options:

1. The ViewModel updates the View.
2. The View observes the ViewModel and updates itself.

In the first case the ViewModel needs a link to the View. I could inject the View into the ViewModel, yet my feeling is it would be better to inject the VieModel into the View.

What is the better style to join them?

Then after rotation the onCreate() method is called again triggering initialisations of the ViewModel a second time. I need to check for this else I am in danger to register listeners to the actual model twice and thrice and similar issues. I may even need to clean up relations to the old view first.

This checking feels kind of unclean. I would expect a dedicated API for this in the ViewModel, if this would be a standard practice. Without I have the feeling to be on the wrong track.

What are good patterns to deal with this in a clean standard way?

Answer (score 2):

Soo.. You don't really have to connect the ViewModel and the Activity/Fragment "with respect to screen rotation", you get that for free - that's one of the perks.

The official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html) is really good.

You connect a ViewModel to your view in `onCreate()` by something like

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        MyViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
        model.getUsers().observe(this, users -> {
            updateUI()
        });
    }
}
```

And while it is true as you say that orientation change will trigger `onCreate()` again, it's not true that this will create a new ViewModel. The `MyViewModel` is only created the first time around in `onCreate`. Re-created activities receive the same `MyViewModel` instance created by the first activity. This is even true for different fragments/activities referencing the same ViewModel.

You should never ever inject a view into the ViewModel. It's the equivalent of drowning puppies. If you need a context in the ViewModel, extend `AndroidViewModel` instead (and pass it the `Application`).

What you do is that you create a ViewModel that holds all state. And handles fetching data from network or disk or what not. All that is not UI related goes in to the ViewModel (as a rule of thumb). All view updating stuff goes into the activity/fragment.

A ViewModel for the example above might look like

```
public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<List<User>> users;

    public LiveData<List<User>> getUsers() {
        if (users == null) {
            users = new MutableLiveData<List<Users>>();
            loadUsers();
        }
        return users;
    }

    private void loadUsers() {
        // Do an asynchronous operation to fetch users.
    }
}
```

This often means that click events should probably be passed down into the ViewModel so that it can massage the data. And the view will just react to the updated (massaged) data.

Comment: Hello! It's not created a second time. The observer is registered a second time. 

Depending on the implementation of `getUsers().observe()` the callback `updateUI()` may be called twice after the first rotation and thrice after the second rotation.

Comment: Then the call to `.getUsers()` draws logic of the model into the view. This is the second reason, why I think this is a rather bad example of the official documentation. 

In my opinion they teach bad practice. Now it's upon us to find out the best practice, at least a better practice.

Comment: Oh, sorry if I misunderstood. But I don't see the problem. If you rotate your screen, your activity goes through its `onDestroy`. Therefore, of course you want the observer to be registered again so that you can get the data to update the UI again - since there is no more UI. Or are you saying that you are getting e.g. 3 consecutive updates in a row?

Comment: And I don't see what you mean with _`.getUsers()` draws logic of the model into the view_. The observers should only draw in (observe) parts of the model that is to be presented to the user. I don't consider that to be a bad thing or bad practice in any way. Or I'm just misunderstanding something, because you clearly seem to see a problem that I don't :)

Comment: Yes, that's what I am saying. Depending on the implementation of `observe()` I get a call to `updateUI()` as many times in a row as it was registered. There is no call to remove it before. You can verify the multiple calls by a log statement or with the debugger.

In the examples I have seen on stackoverflow people implement observables internally with a `List` rather than with a `Set`.

Comment: Just a little smell. 'model.getUsers().observe()` could be replaced by `model.observeUsers()`.

Comment: How would `observeUsers()` look then?

Comment: Let's don't go to deep into that direction. That addresses decoupling and general principles of good architecture. A keyword may be the "Law of Demeter". It's not specific for ViewModels.

Comment: I think the first issue can be answered like this. The call to `.observe()` usually sets an observer of a `ViewModel`. If each view has it's own view model, `observe()` can be a `set()` registration instead of an `add()` registration, a simple property instead of a list of observers. As a result the call to `updateUI()` is only done once because there is no list of observers.

Comment: The example you gave from the official tutorial is a special case. The method `.observe()` is "borrowed" from `LiveData`. I can't predict how it behaves upon multiple registrations of the same activity while rotating.

Also this "borrowing" of the observe method looks a little disputable to me. Do they recommend this as a standard praxis? Then they should name it. Else they should not give such an strange example.

Comment: A gave an answer to the question "How would observeUsers() look then?" here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49511750/android-viewmodel-should-i-borrow-the-observe-method-from-livedata-like-in/49532362#49532362