# Android ViewModel: Should I "borrow" the observe() method from LiveData like in the official example?

Tags: android, observer-pattern, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

When working with ViewModels the View observes the ViewModel. It has to register as an observer. In the [official tutorial](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html) of Google this registration is delegated to the `observe()` method of a `LiveData` object.

```
public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private MutableLiveData<List<User>> users;
    public LiveData<List<User>> getUsers() {
        if (users == null) {
            users = new MutableLiveData<List<Users>>();
            loadUsers();
        }
        return users;
    }

    private void loadUsers() {
        // Do an asynchronous operation to fetch users.
    }
}

public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Create a ViewModel the first time the system calls an activity's onCreate() method.
        // Re-created activities receive the same MyViewModel instance created by the first activity.

        MyViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
        model.getUsers().observe(this, users -> {
            // update UI
        });
    }
}
```

The method `getUsers()` returns the `LiveData` object itself. It's `observe()` method is used to register the observer. The View does not observe the the `ViewModel` but a part of it's implementation.

Now is this best practice, when working with `ViewModels` not to observe themselves but parts of their implementation in form of `LiveData` objects? Or is this an introduction of low quality?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say yes it's best practice for the ViewModel to expose its data through some form of Observable, whether that be LiveData or something like an RX Observable.

This breaks from other architectures such as MVP where the presenter would typically have a reference to the View which gets called when something changes. The guidelines are quite specific about what a ViewModel should reference.

```
A ViewModel must never reference a view, Lifecycle, or any class that may hold a reference to the activity context.
```

By exposing your data as an Observable through the ViewModel this means views can come and go, and once subscribed will receive the latest data and any subsequent updates. Again the guidelines have some detail.

```
If the activity is re-created, it receives the same MyViewModel instance that was created by the first activity. When the owner activity is finished, the framework calls the ViewModel objects's onCleared() method so that it can clean up resources
```

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html

Comment: In first place it breaks a very fundamental principle of object orientated programming, namely encapsulation of the implementation details. I still scratch my head. You are right. If the view should observe the `ViewModel`, the `ViewModel` will hold a reference to the view/activity after registration of the observer. Nonetheless, if I implement it the traditional, encapsulated way, everything keeps working. View and `ViewModel` are cleaned up, when the context goes away, `onCleared()` is called as expected and I even can clean up the reference in `onCleared()` if I want.

Comment: I guess the reason why my classical implementation works is, that the new reference replaces the old reference. For example after rotation the new observer replaces the old observer and the reference is gone. Still this is not really clean. I may be gone to late.

Comment: I can think of a clean solution. For this the registration of the observer must look just like the registration to `LiveData` `observe(LifecycleOwner owner, Observer<T> observer)` itself, taking a `LifecycleOwner` in addition. Then I have every ingredient I need, to delegate to `LiveData` internally without exposing the implementation itself.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of Chris I give my own answer. I think the tutorial is not best practice for the simple reason, that an object should not expose it's internal implementation. Base on the argumentation of Chris I was looking for an option to get encapsulation without losing the named features. The result is the method `observerUsers()` which delegates to a `LiveData` object internally.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MainActivityViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainActivityViewModel.class);
        model.observeUsers(this,
                new Observer<List<User>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChanged(@Nullable List<User> users) {
                        updateUI();
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    void updateUI() {

    }

    static class MainActivityViewModel extends ViewModel {
        private MutableLiveData<List<User>> users;

        public void observeUsers(@NonNull LifecycleOwner owner,
                                 @NonNull Observer<List<User>> observer) {
            getUsers().observe(owner, observer);
        }

        private LiveData<List<User>> getUsers() {
            if (users == null) {
                users = new MutableLiveData<>();
                loadUsers();
            }
            return users;
        }

        private void loadUsers() {
            // Do an asynchronous operation to fetch users.
        }
    }

    static class User {
    }

}
```

Still `List<User>` exposes internal implementation. It could be improved to a class `Users`.

I put everything into one file and use inner static class. This is not meant as best practice. It was just to be able to quickly edit everything within one file. Especially the model `User` belongs into it's very own file, while I often put the `ViewModel` into the `View` class it belongs to like this.

My second point of critic matches the case that the `ViewModel` itself observes an underlying model. In this case the observer method `onChange()` is very general and requires a very general update method like `updateUI()`. You may want to observe more specific events of the model to do specific updates.